# How to measure how much damage i do in a punch

Tags: python, physics, modeling

Which unit do you think it would be best measured in?
I dont know anything about physics... but im using an accelerometer and gyro on the wrist to figure out how hard your punch is. Should i use kinetic energy, force etc?

```
`class PunchForceCalculator:
  def __init__(self, mass_of_hand_and_glove):
    self.mass = mass_of_hand_and_glove

 def calculate_force(self, max_acceleration):
  return self.mass * max_acceleration

mass = 0.5  
calculator = PunchForceCalculator(mass)
max_acceleration = 10  # Max acceleration i m/s^2 (e)
force = calculator.calculate_force(max_acceleration)`
```

ive used this code. but i dont know how much mass is behind the punch, sure the hand but if i have good technique i will punch harder by using my body mass and rotation.
I wanna make a code where i can use my sensor and punch then give it to my friend and measure the results, bad or good technique. should i use another unit? bc the code cant know how much mass you put behind the punch...

Comment: Not sure if this is actually a problem regarding code.

Comment: @Behemoth
you are right.. i mean the equation and then ill put in code :3

Comment: You should measure it as an impulse with units of momentum. An impulse describes a force over time and equates to a momentum change. Essentially start with the mass of the hand _times_ the speed of the punch.  If this momentum is transferred by some proportion over some time slice, you can estimate the _average_ force of the punch.